# Expanding dimension from 3D to 4D using None

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a CNN to solve a problem. The input_shape for first layer I provided was (20, 196, 1).

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, when I do `model.summary()` I get dimensions as (None, 20, 196, 1) and my X is a list of features of dimensions (20, 196, 1). While performing `model.fit()` I get this error -

> Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but
>   got array with shape (20, 196, 1).

[image]

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Also, if I wanted to increase the dimension from (20, 196, 1) to (None, 20, 196, 1), what do I do?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code? It would make it easier to understand the problem

Comment: Is this still a problem? :)

Comment: Not at all. Thankyou. The updated answer solved my problem.

Comment: Could you then accept the answer, please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first axis should always correspond to the batch size. 
For example, consider the case where you can want N elements in your batch. Each element consists of input features with dimension (20, 196, 1). Now, your batch would have a size of (N, 20, 196, 1).

An option would be stacking the samples on the first axis: first, create a list of samples, then assign this to the input data. For example:

```
# list of samples with size (20, 196, 1)
list_of_samples = [x1, x2, x3, .. xn]

# your input data would be:
input_batch = np.array(list_of_samples)
```

Otherwise, if your samples xi are already tensors, another possibility is to stack them on the first axis:

```
# given xi = tensor with shape (20, 196, 1), for i = 1, 2,..., N
input_batch = tf.stack([x1, x2, x3, ..., xn], axis=0)
# input_batch has now shape (N, 20, 196, 1)
```

Comment: So I need to add the number of samples in my train set as the first dimension? Let's say I have 10 samples I want to train the model on, so my tensor becomes (10, 20, 196, 1). Is that right?

Comment: exactly: then you can feed the model with the array of shape (10, 20, 196, 1)

Comment: And can you suggest how to specify this 10 while expanding dimension? As in, if I use np.expand_dims(X, axis=0), it just adds one dimension with (1, 20, 196, 1). How do I make it (10, 20, 196, 1)?